# Returning in protected void super method

Tags: java, inheritance, minecraft

I'm making a spell system for a Minecraft Spigot plugin and I have many layers of inheritance.

```
public class Spell {
    protected void onActivate(Player p) {

    }

    public Spell() {

    }
}
```

This is my base Spell class. Then, I have a class for spells with cooldowns.

```
public class CooldownSpell extends Spell {
    protected int cooldownTicks = 0;
    protected int maxCooldownTicks = 0;
    protected void onActivate(Player p) {
        super.onActivate(p);
        if (cooldownTicks > 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            cooldownTicks = maxCooldownTicks;
            
        }

    }

    public CooldownSpell(int cooldown) {
        this.maxCooldownTicks = maxCooldownTicks;
    }

    // I am using a Bukkit scheduler to decrease cooldown ticks every tick
    public void decreaseCooldownTicks() {
        cooldownTicks--;
    }

    public int getMaxCooldownTicks() {
        return maxCooldownTicks;
    }

    public void setMaxCooldownTicks(int maxCooldownTicks) {
        this.maxCooldownTicks = maxCooldownTicks;
    }
}
```

For those who don't know, a tick in Minecraft is 1/20 of a second.

In onActivate(), there is an if statement: if cooldownTicks is greater than 0, I want to return from this method and all methods calling super.onActivate(). However, this doesn't work in subclasses.

```
public class DamageSpell extends CooldownSpell {
    private double radius;
    private double damage;

    public DamageSpell(int cooldown, double radius, double damage) {
        super(cooldown);
        this.maxCooldownTicks = cooldown;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivate(Player p) {
        super.onActivate(p);
        // spell code stuff here
    }
```

Using the above code, which is a spell that inherits from CooldownSpell, I want to have to same cooldown system as the superclass, but the return statement only returns from the superclass method, not the DamageSpell method.

How can I make the return statement in the onActivate method of the CooldownSpell class return from the onActivate method in any subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that exactly (as far as I know), but what you could do:

```
public class CooldownSpell extends Spell {
    public final void onActivate(Player p) {
        super.onActivate(p);
        if (cooldownTicks > 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            cooldownTicks = maxCooldownTicks;
        }
        this._onActivate(p);
    }
    protected void _onActivate(Player p){}
}

public class DamageSpell extends CooldownSpell {
    private double radius;
    private double damage;

    public DamageSpell(int cooldown, double radius, double damage) {
        super(cooldown);
        this.maxCooldownTicks = cooldown;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void _onActivate(Player p) {
        // spell code stuff here
    }
}
```

And then you just call `onActivate(p)` which, if it doesn't return early, will call your `_onActivate(p)` method.